# D number in Kuiper test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption

I want to use Kuiper test. My question is about the D number in this test. The documentation ([here](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.kuiper.html)), mentions this:

> Returns (D, fpp), where D is the Kuiper D number and fpp is the probability that a value as large as D would occur if data was drawn from cdf.

But what does this "Kuiper D number" mean? Also, how can I interpret this number and found whether the null hypothesis is rejected/accepted for a specific significance level?